# Ncurses не запускается в CLion

Tags: clion, ncurses

После подключения библиотеки `ncurses` в `CMakeLists.txt`, при запуске программы выдается ошибка:

> Error opening terminal: unknown.
>   Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Да, умел я конечно тогда задавать вопросы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости, через CLion на Linux запустить приложение, использующее ncurses не получится. Есть соответствующая задача на [баг-трекере](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-822#tab=Comments), которая не решена.

Comment: Мда.. печаль...